# Adding interstitial ads into SpriteKit game swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I'm trying to implement interstitial ads with iAd into my spriteKit game. My code is as follows:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {

var interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
var interAdView: UIView!


var closeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    closeButton.setTitle("x", forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "close:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
}

func close(sender: UIButton) {
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}
func loadAd() {
    println("load ad")
    interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interAd.delegate = self
}
func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println("ad did load")

    interAdView = UIView()
    interAdView.frame = self.view!.frame
    view!.addSubview(interAdView)

    interAd.presentInView(interAdView)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

    interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("failed to receive")
    println(error.localizedDescription)

    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

This code delivers me more problems than it does results. Unfortunately I am a beginner at implementing any sort of ads into an app and I don't know how I can change any of this in my favour.

One issue I get is that output traces `ad did load` (as you can see thats supposed to be traced once the ad is presented) however when `ad did load` is traced no ad is presented. I wait for at least 3 minutes but nothing happens.

Another issue I have is this `WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once.`, but this is printed after the function to load the ad is called once or twice.

Any help is more than appreciated.